# How to display Plivo sms text on web server?

Tags: php, plivo

hello can you guide me how to get message content using message_url because when i try with message url it gives me all details regarding message but doesn't give text of message.i have already try many times but cant get the solution of it.I attached screenshot of response what i get in message URL.

[Plivo message URL response on web server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkOr7.png)

Comment: You can only receive sms in Plivo

Comment: @Rainmx93  I have talk with support they inform me that they pass message_url to our webserver. But i didn't get how to show them in web server. if you have any idea please share. Thanks in advance.